# SQL Query to select only values that have No default indicator

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have a table that has the following fields:
Primary Key ID
Employee_ID
Default_Indicator (value 'N' or 'Y')
Affiliation (Student, Staff, Faculty)

An employee can be only a Student, Staff or Faculty member.
Whichever they are will have the default indicator = 'Y'

Problem is that Default value for default indicator = 'N'.
Sometimes users wont show up in the application since they don't have a default_Indicator set.

How do I query to find those that have a value of 'N' for Default_indicator, but doesn't have another row having Default_indicator = 'Y'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: tried to add the answer, but for some reason stackoverflow wont allow me to.. some stuff about a cat and some sorta error..

Comment: What do you mean "but doesn't have another row having Default_indicator = 'Y'"? Surely each person will only have *one* row - how can they have "another row"?

Comment: Tried to write an answer and got the cat too.  Here's a summary: You need a nested query.  You can use not exists or not in depending on the size of your table.  This lets you find an employee id that doesn't have a match (with 'Y').  Employee id sounds like a misleading column name though.  They might be a student and not an employee.

Comment: @Bohemian Why?  A faculty member could take classes being a student too.  Or a student can do work study.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employee_ID
FROM [table_name] t
WHERE Default_Indicator = 'N'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
          FROM [table_name] t1
          WHERE t.Employee_ID = t1.Employee_ID
              AND Default_Indicator = 'Y' )
```

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean but I think this should do the trick. Try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
ELECT Employee_ID
FROM [table_name] t
WHERE t.Default_Indicator = 'N' AND t.Employee_ID 
     NOT IN  ( SELECT t1.Employee_ID
          FROM [table_name] t1
              AND t1.Default_Indicator = 'Y' )
```